# Using Pixi JS with React pixi

Tags: reactjs, pixi.js

I'm new here on the platform so if there are some mistakes that I made, please let me know. I wanted to use [pixi js](https://pixijs.com/) as a webGl renderer for one of my projects in Next JS application using a [react wrapper](https://pixijs.io/pixi-react/). The small goal that I'm trying to achieve is I want to create a draggable sprite. But I'm not sure how to do it. I found some examples on the internet but it seems most of them are before pixi version 7. And apparently some APIs are deprecated.

Below is my Next Js component for the sprite. And when I run that, it says that `PixiJS Deprecation Warning: renderer.plugins.interaction has been deprecated, use renderer.events Deprecated since v7.0.0`. And I tried to go through react pixi's documentations but maybe I'm looking at the wrong place but I can't seem to find much in there.

Any tips or help would be appreciated.

```
"use client";

import { Sprite, Stage, useApp } from "@pixi/react";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

export const Thing = () => {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({ x: 400, y: 270 });

  const onDragStart = (event: any) => {
    const sprite = event.currentTarget;
    sprite.alpha = 0.5;
    sprite.data = event.data;
    sprite.dragging = true;
  };

  const onDragEnd = (event: any) => {
    const sprite = event.currentTarget;
    sprite.alpha = 1;
    sprite.dragging = false;
    sprite.data = null;
  };

  const onDragMove = (event: any) => {
    const sprite = event.currentTarget;
    if (sprite.dragging) {
      const newPosition = sprite.data!.getLocalPosition(sprite.parent);
      sprite.x = newPosition.x;
      sprite.y = newPosition.y;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>
        <Sprite
          image="https://pixijs.com/assets/bunny.png"
          
          anchor={0.5}
          x={100}
          y={100}
          pointerdown={onDragStart}
          pointerup={onDragEnd}
          pointerupoutside={onDragEnd}
          pointermove={onDragMove}
        />
      </Stage>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I tried to do several stuffs including using some examples [here](https://pixijs.com/playground?exampleId=events.dragging), but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution :)
Inside your stage component add a prop like so:

```
<Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight} interactive={'auto'}>
```